# User is null in ASP Core 2 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have been attempting to get the current logged in users ID in a ASP Core 2 project in VS 2017. I am using the default template with individual user accounts. I've looked at a lot of resources but still cant figure out why the User Claim always returns null. I can access User info only from the Accounts and Manage Controllers but not from anywhere else.

```
        public async Task<int> GetMinerIDAsync()
    {

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var id = user.Id;

        var query = from x in _context.Miners
                    where x.ApplicationUserID == id
                    select x.ID;
        int a = query.First();
        return a;

    }
```

When I run this code the User is always null.

Comment: share you code plz

Answer (score 0):

This depends on Authentication mode is set to Form or window in your
   web.config.
   If Authentication mode is set to form then change the authentication
   mode to Windows like and run you Application.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Comment: But there is no web.config file for this project. Unless I am missing something